# Search 2 criteria in ListBox in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox

My Code:

```
Sub Search_Click()

Dim x1, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Integer
x1 = [myCar]
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ListBox1
    If TextBox2 = "" Then
        .RowSource = "myCar"
    Else
        .RowSource = ""
        For i = 1 To UBound(x1, 1)
            If LCase(x1(i, 2)) Like LCase(TextBox2) & "*" Then 'Search location column 2

                For ii = 1 To 10
                    .AddItem
                    .List(iii, ii - 1) = x1(i, ii)
                Next
                iii = iii + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

"Search" is CommandButton

"myCar" is name range from A:J (10 columns) in sheet1 and it is RowSource in ListBox1

"TextBox2" is for input searching criteria

When I open UserForm1 , I have another code to sync RowSource("myCar") into ListBox1. After that I can search data in ListBox1 once it is populated.

Above code is for searching data in ListBox1 with single criteria in TextBox2.My code can search data in ListBox1 which is based on criteria in column 2 in RowSource("myCar")

=> My problem :

I want to search data in ListBox1 (After populated) with 2 criteria :

1. TextBox2.value = 1st criteria which is the data in column 2 in range("myCar")
2. TextBox3.value = 2nd criteria which is the data in column 3 in range("myCar")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate to true based on two (or more) criteria, where all must be true, you should use logical operator AND. Example taken from https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/logical-operators.html :

```
Dim score1 As Integer, score2 As Integer, result As String

score1 = Range("A1").Value
score2 = Range("B1").Value

If score1 >= 60 And score2 > 1 Then
    result = "pass"
Else
    result = "fail"
End If

Range("C1").Value = result
```

Modify your if statement to include another criteria using AND operator.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir !!
  
  If LCase(x1(i, 2)) Like LCase(TextBox2) & "*" And LCase(x1(i, 2)) Like LCase(TextBox18) & "*" Then

It does not work.

Your above advice is for 2 conditions of "IF". If I follow your advise I have to create 1 column in the range which data come from TextBox2.value & TexBox3.value. I don't want to do like this. May you advise another solution sir?

Comment: Provide some screen shots with data - it will be easier to get a solution.

Comment: I have 10 column in range(“myCar”). 2nd column is Car Model, 3rd column is Product Year. I want to search data in ListBox based on data in these 2 columns

Comment: Sir? Pls kindly help me

Comment: Click edit under your post, then click sixth icon from left (with a mountain). Attach screen shot and explain in more detail what you want to acomplish. You can simplify your issue using dummy data.